# How do I force a UIAlertView to be the proper size?

Tags: ios, resize, uialertview, sizing

I have a `UIAlertView` that's appearing and blocking input, but the actual "OK/Cancel" is `0×0` at `(0, 0)`, so it's not dismissible by the user. Below is my current fix, but I'd much rather be able to tell iOS "Hey! This isn't right. Make it right." So, **is there any way for me to reposition or reset the position of a `UIAlertView`'s frame in iOS?**

```
if (_floatingAlert &&                                                        // if there is an alert AND...
    (_floatingAlert.visible ||                                               // ( the alert isn't visible OR...
     _floatingAlert.frame.size.height + _floatingAlert.frame.size.width == 0)//  The frame is invisibly small )
    )
{
    [_floatingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    _floatingAlert = nil;
}
```

Comment: i highly doubt the alertview is wrong by itself, did you somehow change it by adding custom buttons or views? you are not allowed to do that.

Comment: basically you just show and MAYBE dismiss it by yourself, but in general, you should not need or even must not add any more code regarding display

Comment: We are not modifying it, no. All we do is `alloc` and `init` it and `show` it.

Comment: you are definitely doing something... fishy...

Answer (score 1):

Uialertview and uiactionsheet are depreciated and though they still work for now you should consider using uialertcontroller.

I am currently working on a project where I came across a couple comments about what you are looking to do. One option would be to set your class as a uialertcontroller delegate which sounded like gave some control over customizing appearance. The other option would be to create your own view that you customize and present it to a user when you need to alert the user of something.

Comment: Thanks! We're not modifying it in any fancy way, so we'll look into replacing our uses of `UIAlertView` with uses of `UIAlertController`.